# Error on simple class in selenium webdrive

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Executing simple class

Enter code here

```
 package lesson1;


import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;



  public class Brf {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //Launches Firefox Browser with blank url
            driver.get("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/login.php");
            driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("admin");
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("admin@123");
            driver.findElement(By.id("tdb1")).click();

            String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            if (url.equals("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/index.php")){
            System.out.println("Login Successful -Passed");
            }
            else 
            {
            System.out.println("Login Unsuccessful -Failed");
            }
            driver.close(); //Closes the Browser
            }




}
```

Getting the error:

```
Error on simple class in selenium webdrive:
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:335)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you haven't set the path of gecko driver in your code.

Please set the path of gecko driver before creating a new instance of Firefox driver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver"," Path to geckodriver");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: u are correct +1, but also write reason so he is not doing same mistake again:P

Answer (score 0):

Need to add driver path, if you are using selenium jars above 3.0 , if you are using selenium jars below 3.0 your code is good to go, but i guess you are using selenium jars above 3.0

```
Public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver"," Path to geckodriver");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/login.php");
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("admin");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("admin@123");
driver.findElement(By.id("tdb1")).click();
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    if (url.equals("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/index.php")){
     System.out.println("Login Successful -Passed");
    }
     else 
     {
      System.out.println("Login Unsuccessful -Failed");
     }
     driver.close(); //Closes the Browser
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is that you don't have a proper setup for detection of a GeckoDriver file named "geckodriver.exe" (this prevents you from being able to open Firefox with your program). In case you don't have such a file, you can download one [h̲e̲r̲e̲](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) (I suggest getting the latest version).

With such a file, you can carry out one of the following two procedures to rectify your problem:

***Method 1***

Add the path of the folder containing the "geckodriver.exe" file to your PATH environment variable value (instructions on how to modify this variable value can be seen [h̲e̲r̲e̲](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html#zz-2.)).

***Method 2***

Prepend the body of your main method with the following statement (where GECKODRIVER_PATH represents the path of the "geckodriver.exe" file):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "GECKODRIVER_PATH");
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the gecko driver path which is initialise the firefox driver.